# Replace only last occurrence of match in a string in VBA

Tags: string, vba, excel, replace

I have a string like this

> "C://Documents/TestUser/WWW/Help/Files/Move_Help.txt"

and have to replace `Move_Help.txt` with `Move_Job.txt`

I am using the below code in VBA EXCEL

```
str = "C://Documents/TestUser/WWW/Help/Files/Move_Help.txt"
rlpStr = Replace(str, 'Help', 'Job')
```

I am getting

```
"C://Documents/TestUser/WWW/Job/Files/Move_Job.txt"
```

Expected

```
"C://Documents/TestUser/WWW/Help/Files/Move_Job.txt"
```

Can you please help on this.

FYI : I can't match Move_Help to Move_Job (Move_ is not constant. It can be any string)

Comment: Is the underscore consistent? If so, you can use `rlpStr = Replace(str, "_Help", "_Job")`.

Comment: It is not. It could any character.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's a one-line solution for this:

```
rlpStr = StrReverse(Replace(StrReverse(str), StrReverse("Help"),  StrReverse("Job"), , 1))
```

Technically, it's slightly less efficient than combining `InStr` and `Replace` but it can be used inside another expression if you need to. Also, I like the one-line solutions so long as they're not incomprehensible.

Answer (score 5):

Would the technique in the code below meet your requirement?

The intial value of Str is:

```
 C://Documents/TestUser/WWW/Help/Files/Move_Help.txt
```

The final value is:

```
 C://Documents/TestUser/WWW/Help/Files/Move_Job.txt
```

The code uses `InStrRev` to locate the last occurrence of `ValueCrnt`, if any,  If `ValueCrnt` is present, it replaces that final occurrence with `ValueNew`.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()

  Dim Pos As Long
  Dim Str As String
  Dim ValueCrnt As String
  Dim ValueNew As String

  Str = "C://Documents/TestUser/WWW/Help/Files/Move_Help.txt"

  ValueCrnt = "Help"
  ValueNew = "Job"

  Pos = InStrRev(Str, ValueCrnt)

  If Pos > 0 Then
    Str = Mid(Str, 1, Pos - 1) & Replace(Str, ValueCrnt, ValueNew, Pos)
  End If

  Debug.Print Str

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Str = "C://Documents/TestUser/WWW/Help/Files/Move_Help.txt"

ValueCrnt = "Help"
ValueNew = "Job"

Pos = InStrRev(Str, ValueCrnt)

If Pos > 0 Then
Str = Mid(Str, 1, Pos - 1) & Replace(Str, ValueCrnt, ValueNew, Pos)
End If

Wscript.Echo Str

Comment: Instead of posting code-only answers, please add some explanation around what the code means.