# Reading VBA TextStream Object Results in Extra Line

Tags: vba, excel, object, outlook

Using the [RangeToHTML](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) function from Ron de Bruin, I'm pasting a range into an outlook email. However, it seems that an extra blank row is being pasted into the email as seen below:[image]

I've already confirmed that the `Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address` line is correctly grabbing only the data itself and not an extra line. I've also confirmed that the input range to `RangetoHTML()` is also correct. My only guess is that the the `.ReadAll` method is somehow putting an extra line in the file, but I'm not sure how to debug that. Here's the `RangetoHTML` function I'm using for easy reference:

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' By Ron de Bruin.
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
If rng Is Nothing Then GoTo Skip

rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    .Cells(1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1)
RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing

Skip:

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

EDIT: Here's the portion of code where the email is being generated. The `RangeToHTML(rng_Summary)` is what inserts the range into the email:

```
'Construct the actual email in outlook
With OutMail
    .to = "LastName, FirstName"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "LOB Break Status (As of " & Format(Now(), "m/d") & ")"
    .HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Here is the latest status for the breaks, by product, in the LOB:" & _
                RangetoHTML(rng_Summary) & _
                "<BODY style=font-size:9pt;font-family:Calibri>*allows are excluded from Avg. Age of Breaks calculation" & _
                "<ul>" & _
                    "<li>" & _
                        "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri><u><b>Average Age of Breaks</u></b>" & Chr(150) & " " & avg_age_change & " from " & avg_break_age_prev & " to " & avg_break_age_curr & " due to ________" & _
                    "</li>" & _
                "</ul>"
    .Display 'CHANGE THIS to .Display/.Send if you want to test/send
End With
```

Comment: Sometimes the data may end with two (2) `LF`'s.

Comment: Can you post the full HTML? From what I can see, your HTML might have a few issues. The snippet you've posted has three Body tags (four if you include the result from RangetoHTML) Could you try and email a copy to yourself and then view the source of that email to see where it might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Workbook.PublishObjects` includes an extra row to enforce column widths.

```
 <![if supportMisalignedColumns]>
 <tr height=0 style='display:none'>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
 </tr>
 <![endif]>
```

Using the @EngineerToast's answer to  [Replace only last occurrence of match in a string in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394833/replace-only-last-occurrence-of-match-in-a-string-in-vba) we can hide the last row while preserving column widths.

```
Function getTrimRangetoHTML(rng As Range) As String
    Const OldText = "display:none"
    Const NewText = "visibility: hidden;"
    Dim s As String
    s = RangetoHTML(rng)
    s = StrReverse(Replace(StrReverse(s), StrReverse(OldText), StrReverse(NewText), , 1))
    getTrimRangetoHTML = s

    With CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        .SetText s
        .PutInClipboard
    End With
End Function
```

### Addendum

After reviewing RangetoHTML's output I noticed that the first row also enforces the column widths.  Nonetheless, getTrimRangetoHTML will give the desired result of hidding the last row.

Comment: The replace works as expected (verified with `Debug.Print`), but the extra line persists at the bottom. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure.  You might be interested in my post on Code Review: [Creating HTML using a Builder Pattern](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/178814/creating-html-using-a-builder-pattern).  It contains a class that makes it easy to build HTML.

Comment: Haven't taken a look at that post just yet, but I figured that if I could set a condition for the IF block to never execute, then the additional row wouldn't happen. So, I did `Const OldText = "supportMisalignedColumns" ` and `Const NewText = "1=0"`. Not elegant, but it suits my purpose. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @kschindl cleaver. How about `HTML = Replace(HTML, "supportMisalignedColumns", False)`?   Thanks for accepting my answer

Answer (score 0):

I've had this exact same thing happen to me, and I fixed it using some simple CSS.

```
tr:last-child {display:none;}
```

If you are not familiar CSS, that needs to be placed between style tags, like this:

```
<style> tr:last-child {display:none;} </style>
```

Placed here in your code:

```
RangetoHTML = "<style> tr:last-child {display:none;} </style>" & Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")
```

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: This didn't solve the issue for me :(. The cells copied into the email still have an extra blank row at the bottom.

Comment: That's odd. Works just fine for me. Not really sure what to tell you. Maybe someone else will have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have to include the following code line before `'Close TempWB` within the RangeToHTML procedure to avoid an additional line  on top of `HTML Body`:

```
    ' >>> INSERTED CODE LINE:
      RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "<!--[if !excel]>&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->", "")

    ' Close TempWB
      TempWB.Close savechanges:=False
    ' .... 
    ' ....
```