# Adding the word 'and' to a list in a message box

Tags: vba, ms-access, msgbox

I need help getting started on the code for adding the word 'and' to a message box after the user has selected items from a list box to make the message box grammatically correct.  Possibly removing the last comma too.

```
Private Sub cmdSelect_Click()
Dim IntIndex As Integer, strSelectedHHItems As String
For IntIndex = 0 To lstHouseHoldItems.ListCount
    If lstHouseHoldItems.Selected(IntIndex) Then
        strSelectedHHItems = strSelectedHHItems & "," & " " & lstHouseHoldItems.Column(0, IntIndex)
    End If
Next
strSelectedHHItems = Right(strSelectedHHItems, Len(strSelectedHHItems) - 1)'remove beginning space
MsgBox "You have selected" & (strSelectedHHItems)
End Sub
```

[image: Message box needs to read Chair, Couch **AND** Nighstand.]

I am an amateur, I know it will require the use of some intrinsic functions like Mid or Len but I can't think of how to do it.  Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Search for "ms access find last comma and replace with and" ;)

Comment: Thank you buddy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace only last occurrence of match in a string in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394833/replace-only-last-occurrence-of-match-in-a-string-in-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you know the location of the last comma, just string together your new string:

```
loc = InStrRev(strSelectedHHItems, ",")
strSelectedHHItems = Mid(strSelectedHHItems, 1, loc - 1) & " and " & Mid(strSelectedHHItems, loc + 2)
```